# Github storage issue in iOS

Tags: ios, git

in my project there is a hidden git file of 1.2 GB can i delete this object folder

find the attached screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Git stores the complete history of your files for a project in a special directory (a.k.a. a folder) called a repository, or repo. This repo is usually in a hidden folder called .git

In your project directory .git hidden file denotes that your project directory is under version control.

if you delete .git hidden file then you simply removing version control from your project directory and you lost all tracking of your project directory. So Never ever delete .git file if you want your project directory under version control.